# Installation of OpenFOAM throws read-only file system error while using Docker

Tags: bash, docker, openfoam

I'm trying to install OpenFOAM on Mac with Docker. I followed this tutorial. After I ran `docker run -ti openfoamplus/of_v30plus_rhel66 /bin/bash` to start downloading, it threw the error

```
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): lchown /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v3.0+/tutorials/discreteMethods: read-only file system.
```

AFTER the download finished. I've tried it multiple times: still the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Since the error message complains about a  "read-only file system," have you tried making that directory tree read-write?  Alternatively, have a look at the `umask` for the user doing the install.  It might need to be changed.  OpenFOAM is not widely used and it is common for installation scripts for such packages to be less than perfect.

Comment: @John1024 I can't add permissions specifically to the OpenFOAM directory because that is created after I start the installation. I could add them to /opt/, though. Is that safe? Also, does `chmod` add perms to the file if it is created after the command was run?

Comment: @John1024 My `umask` is `0022`. I think that means newly created files are readable and writable for the creator, correct?

Comment: 0022 should be OK.  No, you can't run chmod before the file is created.  But, you may be able to hack the installation script to put in a chmod command where it is needed.